# Hyper-V server 2012 connect to VM

Tags: hyper-v, hyper-v-server-2012

I just finished setting up a server core version of hyper-v 2012.  The problem I am running into is connecting to a VM via powershell.  I recognize that I use a server 2012 or win 8 machine to manage the server remotely and connect to a running VM that way but I can not find a command that will let me do it.  Am I missing something?  Does a command to connect to running VM exist?

Answer (score 4):

For Windows 8, you first need to install [Remote Server Administration Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972).

First ensure that you have the Hyper-V management tools installed. You can do this by Add Roles and Features from Server Manager.
[image]

(While you can [configure Hyper-V with PowerShell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848559.aspx), you also need the GUI tools installed to actually make a remote connection to the virtual machine.)

### Command line method

Call `vmconnect` from the command line to connect to a specific server and virtual machine. The options for `vmconnect` are:
[image]

### GUI method

Now open Hyper-V Virtual Machine Connection.
[image]

Then select the Hyper-V server you want to connect to, then the virtual machine on that server.
[image]